# How to configure jdbc-realm to jBoss jbpm

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, jbpm

I'm trying to use my user and roles tables in jBPM 6.

I've configured my standalone.xml like this.

```
<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/autenticacionDS"/> 
                        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from usuario where  nombreusuario=?"/>  
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select nombre, 'Roles' from rol r inner join rolusuario ru on ru.rolid= r.id inner join usuario u on ru.usuarioid = u.id where u.nombreusuario=?"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

I've added "user" role in order to log in to KIE Workbench.

My log appears to look for users and roles in a properties file and a warning telling me that my options are invalid.

```
Invalid or misspelled module option: rolesQuery
 Failed to load users/passwords/roles files: java.io.IOException: PBOX000072: Properties file users.properties/defaultUsers.properties not found
```

My web.xml looks like

```
 <filter>
<filter-name>UberFire Security Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.uberfire.security.server.UberFireSecurityFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.uberfire.cookie.id</param-name>
  <param-value>kie.ide.console</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.uberfire.auth.scheme</param-name>
  <param-value>org.uberfire.security.server.auth.JACCAuthenticationScheme</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.uberfire.auth.rememberme</param-name>
  <param-value>disabled</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
  <param-name>org.uberfire.auth.force.url</param-name>
  <param-value>/org.kie.workbench.KIEWebapp/KIEWebapp.html</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I think I need to change something like org.uberfire.security.server.auth.JDBCAuthenticationScheme or something like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related to jBoss AS7, the UsersRoles login module is for user and roles files only.
You need to use the Database login module. Here is a post on how to use it http://middlewaremagic.com/jboss/?p=387

Comment: What should I change in order to complete Step 5

Comment: I moved from property files to LDAP authentication without changing web.xml because the file already has the xml elements the post is mentioning. For step 6 you don't need to prefix the security-domain name name with "java:/jaas/"